# icons displaying small and full screen not displaying in galaxy tab3

Tags: android, layout

Hi In this below layout small android mobiles everything working fine.Whwn I am testing in tab 3 icons displaying small size and full screen not occupying.I mentions all the image sizes 48x48,72x72,96x96,144x144,192x192 But displaying only small icons.

This layout also not occupying full screen.
Can any one please help me out from this issue.
**home.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.0" 
        android:layout_margin="25dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/aboutus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AboutUs"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/playgroup" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play Group"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facilites" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facilites" 
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.0"

       android:layout_margin="25dp">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tourourschool" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tour Our School"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/career" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Carrers"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/admission" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Admission Enquiry"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.0"
        android:layout_margin="25dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/parent" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Parents Resoures" 
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/contactus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ContactUs" 
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/livechat" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Live Chat" 
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Check whether the images are placed in proper folder or not.. that is drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi etc. and in resource folder create a folder 'layout-xlarge' and design the xml file according to that screen size.

Comment: same like that only I kept all the images in res->folder

Comment: the icons in separate folders(hdpi,ldpi etc) having same names or different names?

Comment: same name i gave in all the places

Comment: did u put icons in folder 'drawable-xhdpi' ?

Comment: try clean and build and run the project